# Обратиться к дочернему элементу через индекс jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

есть у меня div c набором дочерних div внутри

```
 <div id="indiv">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>2</div>
 </div>
```

все они могут быть или скрыты или показанны все или кто то из них конкретно, задача такова что бы скрыть все и показать только один из них, есть js который этим занимается - сут в том что есть переменная i которая содержит индекс элемента который надо показать, по этмоу я сначало скрываю все элепенты, а потом показываю только тот который нужен вот так:

```
 $('#indiv').children('div').fadeOut(300);
 $('#indiv').children('div')[i].fadeIn(300);
```

но элементы скрываются, а в замент не показывается нужный, при том что i сожержит соответствующий индекс (в данном случае от 0 да 2)
подскажите как правильно обращаться к дочерним элементам по индексу??

Comment: если обращаться через [i] ты получишь доступ к dom элементу с таким номером в наборе jquery вместо  объекта jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#indiv').children('div').eq(i).fadeIn(300);
```